# Acentos y "ñ" mostrados incorrectamente en base de datos Maria

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Cuando inserto datos en mi base MariaDB desde un formulario de mi página web (cuya extensión es ".php"), la "ñ" o los acentos se transforman en caracteres extraños.

- En mi código html tengo bien especificado el conjunto de caracteres: charset="utf8".
- Mi PHPMYADMIN tiene esta configuración (la que vino por defecto): "Conjunto de caracteres del servidor: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)".
- Y el cotejamiento de la base de datos con la que estoy trabajando es "utf8_spanish_ci".
- No es el php, porque cuando escribo en el documento php, los caracteres aparecen bien.

¿Alguien sabe qué puede ser y cómo solucionarlo?
Pienso que podría ser la codificación por defecto de la base de datos. Es utf8 pero podría ser otra combinación... Pero no sé cómo cambiarla.

Comment: Tienes configurado el `charset` en tu conexión a la base de datos ?

Comment: Favor coloca tu `código php` con el que realizas la `conexión` a la base de datos.

Answer (score 2):

Es tu codificación cuando abres la conexión desde PHP.
Intenta agregar esta línea antes de usar la conexión

```
mysqli_set_charset($tu_conexion,"utf8");
```

Si la base de datos estuviera mal configurada te aparecerían caracteres extraños en tus SELECTS directos.

Comment: Se solucionó con tu código..pero tuve que ponerlo al final de la conexión, porque cuando la puse al comienzo me tiró un mensaje de error, decía "undefinied"..

Comment: Asi: $maria = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', ''123 'LOGIC') ; mysqli_set_charset($maria,"utf8");

Comment: Gracias... ¿como cierro el tema, o como te doy puntos? Hasta ahora no sé como funciona esto.

Comment: ¿Y que fue lo que pasó? Porque si tenía bien configurado mi php, mi base de datos, me pasó esto. O sea donde estaba el error exactamente, en php ??

Comment: Si en  PHP, es un error muy común de entendimiento entre el backend y la base de datos. Para puntuar en tu lado izquierdo hay un contador, puedes puntuar hacia arriba o hacia abajo. Debajo del puntuador hay una palomita desmarcada, sólo dale click hasta que quede verde. Que bueno que te sirvió.

Comment: No me aparecen ninguna de esas opciones que mencionas. A la izquierda solo dice "inicio, preguntas, etiquetas, usuarios"..y a la derecha y en los otros lados no aparece nada de eso.. Quizá sea porque no estoy registrado.. O no sé. Gracias por la ayuda.